# Python Class Method not returning imported class method?

Tags: python, function, class-method

I have a class which takes in a user choice (below)

```
from MiniProject1.interfaces.s_selection import SecondarySelection as SS  # 
imports the secondary_selection function from selections
import MiniProject1.interfaces.newcastle_cm as IT
from MiniProject1.Newcastle.newcastle_cc import ColumnCalculation as CC

class Newcastle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key_typed = input(str("Select what you want to do: "))

    @staticmethod
    def column_or_graph():
        if SS.get_input(SS.display_input()) is True:
            IT.column_manipulation()
            return True
        IT.graph_plotting()
        return False

    def column_selection(self):
        if self.key_typed == 1:
            CC.total_electricity()  # Calls the total_electricity method
        elif self.key_typed == 2:
            pass
        elif self.key_typed == 3:
            pass
        elif self.key_typed == 4:
            pass
        elif self.key_typed == 5:
            pass

def main():
    if Newcastle.column_or_graph() is True:
        Newcastle.column_selection(Newcastle())
    elif Newcastle.column_or_graph() is False:
        Newcastle.graph_plotting(Newcastle())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The first part seems to run without issue, as the imported functions `SS.get_input(SS.display_input())` from a class work without any issues and return either True or False, and when they do `Newcastle.column_selection(Newcastle())` works as well, as it displays the interface and takes the user input.
So, all that seems to work. But when the user selects 1 it should return the `CC.total_electricity()` method, but instead it just ends the program. 
I've tried `return CC.total_electricity()` as well, but that just does the same thing as well, and doesn't work. Is there any idea to why this may be? I've been working on it all day.

The CC.total_electricity class method looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
class ColumnCalculation:
    """This houses the functions for all the column manipulation calculations"""

    @staticmethod
    def total_electricity():
        """Calculates the total amount of electricity used per year"""
        df = pd.read_csv("2011-onwards-city-elec-consumption.csv", thousands=',')
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)  # Sets index to months
        df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()  # Creates a new row for the totals of each year
        return print(df)  # Prints the dataframe
```

And that has been tried, and tested to work, it's just when I import it it doesn't return anything and ends the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare the user input to an integer:

```
if self.key_typed == 1:
```

Therefore, you need to convert your input into an integer too.

So instead:

```
self.key_typed = input(str("Select what you want to do: "))
```

do:

```
self.key_typed = int(input("Select what you want to do: "))
```